# Problem with lowercase Greek letters

Tags: greek, letters

I'm having a problem writing a cover page for a book in Greek. The lowercase Greek letters doesn’t appear. I'm using the packages:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsopn} 
\usepackage[fleqn,leqno]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

etc.

I notice that the same problem appears in the mathematical environment, and I can write Greek & English throughout the book without any problem. Of course, I don’t like to use Greek letters like `\alpha` etc.

Comment: Please augment your code snippet to provide an example of how things are going wrong on the cover page and in mathematical environments.

Comment: A code snippet is: \begin{document}
% command to provide stretchy vertical space in proportion
\newcommand\nbvspace[1][3]{\vspace*{\stretch{#1}}}
% allow some slack to avoid under/overfull boxes
\newcommand\nbstretchyspace{\spaceskip0.5em plus 0.25em minus 0.25em}
\newcommand{\nbtitlestretch}{\spaceskip0.6em}
\pagecolor{darkcyan}
\afterpage{\nopagecolor}
\begin{center}
\bfseries
\nbvspace[1]
\Huge
{\nbtitlestretch\LARGE
Άλγεβρα για τα Λύκεια}
\nbvspace[1]
\normalsize
$\text{Γ' Λυκείου}$
\nbvspace[1]
\small Dr. \\
\Large $\text{Σπύρος Καναβός}$
 \end{center}
\end{document}

Answer (score 2):

I think that by now -- late 2021 -- all LaTeX users of non-Latin alphabets would do themselves a huge favor by (a) switching from pdfLaTeX to either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX and (b) using the facilities of the `fontspec` and `unicode-math` packages along with suitably chosen OpenType text and math fonts.

For sure, if I modify your code to make use of `fonspec` and its "big brother" (`unicode-math`), none of the issues you mention in your posting crop up.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%%%%\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor} % 'svgnames' defines 'DarkCyan'
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsopn} 
\usepackage[fleqn,leqno]{amsmath}
%%%%\usepackage{amsmath} % <-- don't load packages more than once
\usepackage{afterpage}

% command to provide stretchy vertical space in proportion 
\newcommand\nbvspace[1][3]{\vspace*{\stretch{#1}}} 
% allow some slack to avoid under/overfull boxes 
\newcommand\nbstretchyspace{\spaceskip0.5em plus 0.25em minus 0.25em} 
\newcommand{\nbtitlestretch}{\spaceskip0.6em} 

%% new:
\usepackage{unicode-math} % 'unicode-math' loads 'fontspec' automatically
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}     % <-- select a suitable text font
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths} % <-- select a suitable math font

\begin{document} 
\pagecolor{DarkCyan} 
\afterpage{\nopagecolor} 

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{center} 
\bfseries 

\nbvspace[1] 
\Huge \nbtitlestretch

\LARGE Άλγεβρα για τα Λύκεια

\nbvspace[1] 
\normalsize Γ' Λυκείου

\nbvspace[1] 
\small Dr. 
 
\Large Σπύρος Καναβός
\end{center} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: I made some modifications to the program, because I’m working on Xelatex.
For example, I set \usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} instead of \usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor} and \pagestyle{empty} instead of \thispagestyle{empty}. The colors are defined by using the tables with Triplet RGB or Hex. e.g. \definecolor{darkcyan}{rgb}{0.0, 0.55, 0.55}. It works perfect. Thanks a lot.